# Implicit nullable cast inside if condition

Tags: c#, casting, nullable

I recently found some code with nullable `if` condition like this:

```
bool? nullableVariable;
//some lines of code involving nullableVariable
if (nullableVariable == true)
{
    //some other lines of code
}
```

at first sight I thought it as potentially exception prone. My opinion was based on the fact that:

```
bool? nullableVariable = null;
bool variable = (bool)nullableVariable
```

would raise error *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'* and I expected that inside the `if (nullableVariable == true)` statement a cast of left operand from `bool?` to `bool` would be performed (my impression confirmed by the fact that moving cursor on `==` operator results in Visual Studio hint *bool bool.operator == (bool left, bool right)*).

Given that, I've been surprised seeing that:

```
bool? nullableVariable = null;
if (nullableVariable == true)
{
    //some other lines of code
}
```

would not raise exception (skipping the code inside brackets).

So the question is: what is happening inside that `if` statement? maybe a hidden `try-catch` cast of left operand from `bool?` to `bool` with `catch` setting the result to false? or maybe right operand cast from `bool` to `bool?`? or something else?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [lifted operators in Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators)

I short, they are overloaded for comparisons like `==`:

> For the equality operator ==, if both operands are null, the result is
> true, if only one of the operands is null, the result is false;
> otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared.

So by comparing with `true` or `false` you can avoid handling the case that the nullable is `null` which makes the code more readable like in your example:

```
if (nullableVariable == true)
{
    //some other lines of code
}
```

So whenever you compare(`==` or `!=`) a  `bool?` with a `bool` the result is not a `bool?`(or `null`) but a `bool` with the rules described in the link above. That's why you can use it in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, **the equality operators are lifted** to the nullable equivalents.

**There does seem to be slight differences in the way it is compiled.** I'm not entirely sure why, but it may be to do with lack of compiler knowledge whether an operator is side-effecting for complex structs, whereas types like `int` and `bool` it knows what's going on.

Where `A` and `B` are nullables then,

```cs
A == B
```

This is compiled to the following for basic types like `int`:

```cs
(A.GetValueOrDefault() == B.GetValueOrDefault()) && (A.HasValue == B.HasValue)
```

And to this for more complex types:

```cs
(A.HasValue == B.HasValue) ? !A.HasValue ||  (A.GetValueOrDefault() == B.GetValueOrDefault())
```